# Pandas include Key to json file

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'http://www.fundamentus.com.br/resultado.php'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
fundamentus = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


dfs = pd.read_html(fundamentus.text)
table = dfs[0]
table.to_json('table7.json', orient='records', indent=2)
```

this is giving me the following:

```
[{
    "Papel":"VNET3",
    "Cota\u00e7\u00e3o":0.0,
    "P\/L":0.0,
    "P\/VP":0.0,
    "PSR":0.0,
    "Div.Yield":"0,00%",
    "P\/Ativo":0.0,
    "P\/Cap.Giro":0,
    "P\/EBIT":0.0,
    "P\/Ativ Circ.Liq":0,
    "EV\/EBIT":0.0,
    "EV\/EBITDA":0.0,
    "Mrg Ebit":"0,00%",
    "Mrg. L\u00edq.":"0,00%",
    "Liq. Corr.":0,
    "ROIC":"0,00%",
    "ROE":"12,99%",
    "Liq.2meses":"000",
    "Patrim. L\u00edq":"9.257.250.00000",
    "D\u00edv.Brut\/ Patrim.":0.0,
    "Cresc. Rec.5a":"-2,71%"
  },
  {
    "Papel":"CFLU4",
    "Cota\u00e7\u00e3o":1.0,
    "P\/L":0.0,
    "P\/VP":0.0,
    "PSR":0.0,
    "Div.Yield":"0,00%",
    "P\/Ativo":0.0,
    "P\/Cap.Giro":0,
    "P\/EBIT":0.0,
    "P\/Ativ Circ.Liq":0,
    "EV\/EBIT":0.0,
    "EV\/EBITDA":0.0,
    "Mrg Ebit":"8,88%",
    "Mrg. L\u00edq.":"10,72%",
    "Liq. Corr.":110,
    "ROIC":"17,68%",
    "ROE":"32,15%",
    "Liq.2meses":"000",
    "Patrim. L\u00edq":"60.351.00000",
    "D\u00edv.Brut\/ Patrim.":6.0,
    "Cresc. Rec.5a":"8,14%"
  }
]
```

But I need the following.

```
[ VNET3 = {
    "Cota\u00e7\u00e3o":0.0,
    "P\/L":0.0,
    "P\/VP":0.0,
    "PSR":0.0,
    "Div.Yield":"0,00%",
    "P\/Ativo":0.0,
    "P\/Cap.Giro":0,
    "P\/EBIT":0.0,
    "P\/Ativ Circ.Liq":0,
    "EV\/EBIT":0.0,
    "EV\/EBITDA":0.0,
    "Mrg Ebit":"0,00%",
    "Mrg. L\u00edq.":"0,00%",
    "Liq. Corr.":0,
    "ROIC":"0,00%",
    "ROE":"12,99%",
    "Liq.2meses":"000",
    "Patrim. L\u00edq":"9.257.250.00000",
    "D\u00edv.Brut\/ Patrim.":0.0,
    "Cresc. Rec.5a":"-2,71%"
  },
  CFLU4 = {
    "Cota\u00e7\u00e3o":1.0,
    "P\/L":0.0,
    "P\/VP":0.0,
    "PSR":0.0,
    "Div.Yield":"0,00%",
    "P\/Ativo":0.0,
    "P\/Cap.Giro":0,
    "P\/EBIT":0.0,
    "P\/Ativ Circ.Liq":0,
    "EV\/EBIT":0.0,
    "EV\/EBITDA":0.0,
    "Mrg Ebit":"8,88%",
    "Mrg. L\u00edq.":"10,72%",
    "Liq. Corr.":110,
    "ROIC":"17,68%",
    "ROE":"32,15%",
    "Liq.2meses":"000",
    "Patrim. L\u00edq":"60.351.00000",
    "D\u00edv.Brut\/ Patrim.":6.0,
    "Cresc. Rec.5a":"8,14%"
  }
]
```

The enconding is comming wrongly as well.
**For example: "Cota\u00e7\u00e3o"**

I tried: `table.to_json('table7.json',**force_ascii=True**, orient='records', indent=2)`

I also tried.

```
table.to_json('table7.json',**encoding='utf8'**, orient='records', indent=2)
```

But no success.

So I tried to read with json because the Idea was read it and convert it.

This is the json reader statement.

```
jasonfile = open('table7.json', 'r')
stocks = jasonfile.read()
jason_object = json.loads(stocks)
print(str(jason_object['Papel']))
```

But I've got.

```
  **print(str(jason_object['Papel']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have list with many dictionaries - you need `[0]` to get first dictionary - `jason_object[0]['Papel']`

Comment: text `Cota\u00e7\u00e3o` can be correct - try `print('Cota\u00e7\u00e3o')` it gives me `Cotação` - but in JSON file it may have to keep native chars like `\u00e7`

Comment: BTW: `[ VNET3 = { .. }]` it is not correct JSON. Correct JSON can be `{ "VNET3": { .. } }`

Answer (score 0):

You have list with many dictionaries so you have to use index like `[0]` to get one dictionary

```
print( jason_object[0]['Papel'] )
```

And text `Cota\u00e7\u00e3o` can be correct. It is how JSON keeps native chars.

But if you print it

```
print('Cota\u00e7\u00e3o')
```

then you should get

```
Cotação
```

When I run

```
for key in jason_object[0].keys():
    print(key)
```

then I get on screen

```
VNET3
Papel
Cotação
P/L
P/VP
PSR
Div.Yield
P/Ativo
P/Cap.Giro
P/EBIT
P/Ativ Circ.Liq
EV/EBIT
EV/EBITDA
Mrg Ebit
Mrg. Líq.
Liq. Corr.
ROIC
ROE
Liq.2meses
Patrim. Líq
Dív.Brut/ Patrim.
Cresc. Rec.5a
```

But if I open `table7.json` in text editor then I see `Cota\u00e7\u00e3o`

---

List `[ VNET3 = { .. }]` it is not correct `JSON` nor Python structure.

Correct `JSON` and Python structure is dictionary `{ "VNET3": { .. } }`

```
new_data = dict()

for item in jason_object:
    key = item['Papel']
    item.pop('Papel')
    val = item
    new_data[key] = val

print(new_data)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'http://www.fundamentus.com.br/resultado.php'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)
table = dfs[0]
table.to_json('table7.json', orient='records', indent=2)

jasonfile = open('table7.json', 'r')
jason_object = json.loads(jasonfile.read())

#print(jason_object[0]['Papel'])

#for key in jason_object[0].keys():
#    print(key)

new_data = dict()

for item in jason_object:
    key = item['Papel']
    item.pop('Papel')
    val = item
    new_data[key] = val

print(new_data)
```

---

Tested on Python 3.7, Linux Mint which as default uses `UTF-8` in console/terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was trying to understand this part here.

for item in jason_object:
    key = item['Papel']
    item.pop('Papel')
    val = item
    new_data[key] = val

print(new_data)


Whats does this ".pop" item.pop('Papel') ? 
I didn't get this .pop I was working hard to get it functional.

Comment: I managed to find here that this .pop remove an Item.
make totally sense, thats awesome.
Thanks a lot.